# Relay: Fragment cannot condition on unknown type "viewer"

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs

Im trying to compile my Relay app but Im getting the error when trying to compile:

```
yarn run relay-compiler --src ./src --schema ./src/schema.graphql --extensions=js --extensions=jsx
```

Throws:

```
Writing js
ERROR:
Fragment "ListPage_viewer" cannot condition on unknown type "Viewer".
error Command failed with exit code 100.
```

The component that Im trying to compile is the following:

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    createFragmentContainer,
    graphql
} from 'react-relay'

const ListPage = ({
    viewer
}) => (
    <div>
        {JSON.stringify({viewer})}
    </div>
)

export default createFragmentContainer(ListPage, graphql`
    fragment ListPage_viewer on Viewer {
        posts(last:100) @connection(key: "ListPage_posts", filters: []){
            edges {
                node {
                    ...Post_post
                }
            }
        }
    }
`)
```

Info
Some dependencies Im using are:

```
"babel-plugin-relay": "^8.0.0",
"relay-compiler": "^8.0.0"
"react-relay": "^8.0.0",
```

Comment: Does the `schema.graphql` file you're passing in actually have a `Viewer` *type*?

Comment: @DanielRearden No, it doesnt. Im following a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XeALXh37WeU) and the schema is extracted directly from the server (that I couldnt reproduce), which I realiced its this one: https://github.com/graphcool-examples/react-graphql/blob/master/quickstart-with-relay-modern/schema.graphql. No idea about the meaning of `viewer: Viewer!`